# Python urllib2 error works on PC but not on raspberrypi

Tags: python, urllib2

Hi I've been trying to execute the python code below on the raspberry pi, but have encountered an error that doesn't exist on my PC

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
print response.info()
html = response.read()
# do something
response.close()
```

Error is as follows but I do not understand what is wrong here can someone please explain what is happening? I have urllib2 installed in the pi already:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing1.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an internet connection on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Also, use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) you'll be much happier doing so.

Comment: But I tried the internet connection with Midori in the pi, and it is working fine.